# How to make a table fill 100% width adjusting font-size

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a table with two tds, I want to make it's font-size to fill the entire width.
If each td have the letter a, each letter will occupy 50% width.
If I have x number of tds with the letters 'a b def g h' each letter will occupy (100% / 7) 14% of the screen width.

Preferably just css, no javascript;

Comment: I don't think this can be accomplished with vanilla CSS

Comment: I believe you'll have to use javascript to count the number of characters, then divide 100% by that number to get the value for the width of each character. Then you'll have to convert that into the font size that gives that character the specified width...